# Transparent authentication for a application in Outlook 365 (in-prem MS AD and Azure involved)

Tags: outlook, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

i have the following network configuration:
- in-premise MS AD 2012 + Federation Services
- MS AD Azure
domains are in-sync.

let's say, i have a in-prem user, currently logged into the domain via SSO.
I need to develop an application working in a browser, which meets the following criteria:
- application should allow a currently logged domain user to create appointments in the application UI and export them into the Outlook 365.

- application should allow a currently logged domain user to create taks in the application UI and export them into the Outlook 365.
- application should support transparent login into MS AD Azure (Outlook 365) for a currently logged domain user (user should not provide with his credentials on the Outlook 365 side).

After digging the internet, i've found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-authentication-authorization , but still i cannot draw the entire picture.
Could you guys please point me in the right direction, if you have similar experience?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have federation enabled from Azure AD to ADFS, the flow with Web apps looks something like this:

1. User navigates to your app
2. Redirect user to Azure AD for authentication

   - Here you can give a `domain_hint` as a parameter if you know the domain where your users will sign in.
   - Azure AD will suggest their account if they are already signed in to Azure AD. In that case the flow goes to step 8.
3. User enters their username
4. User gets redirected to ADFS
5. If user is accessing ADFS from within the on-prem network, they get automatically signed in. Otherwise they will need to enter their password at this point.
6. User gets redirected back Azure AD
7. Multi-factor authentication is done if enabled
8. User consent for permissions required by application is handled

   - E.g. permissions to access the user's email
   - An admin can consent for every user in a tenant, if you do that then no one else will be asked for consent.
9. User gets redirected back to your app

Before all of this can happen, you will of course need to register your app in Azure AD. There you can define what permissions it requires e.g. on the Microsoft Graph API.

Also, check out the Seamless SSO page in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso. This approach does require you to enable either password sync or pass-through authentication.

Comment: thank you @juunas !
i have an additional question. if I understand correctly, step#2 implies an explicit redirect of webpage to remote authorization gateway. 
Is there a way to authorize a user implicitely via background intercommunication with remote Outlook 365? 
The application i'm currently working on is a client-server application and i'd like to work with remote system on server side.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that.

Comment: And you should note that if the user already signed into Office 365, the redirects will just flash quickly, and the user will be back in the app fully authenticated (if they are in the local network with the Domain Controller).

Comment: the main idea is to give a user a feasibility not to provide with his credentials for Outlook 365 if he has already been logged into the local domain via ADFS (which is in-sync with remote MS AD Azure). will it work this way (having in mind your process described above)?

Comment: Do your users have a local connection to a domain controller either through corporate network or VPN?

Comment: users in corporate network (Active Directory 2008 domain controller with Federation Services, let's assume no VPN users).

Comment: Then you should be able to just define the `domain_hint` parameter when redirecting to Azure AD. It should redirect the user straight to ADFS since it knows that domain is federated. Thanks to home realm discovery, the user would then get signed against the domain via windows authentication. This means the user never has to type anything.

Comment: That assumes all your users come from a single domain of course.